# How to stop aggregating Data to Parent level in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, aggregation

[image]

Data will be always entered at Level 3, and data has to be aggregated from child to parent

**Dax: Total1 = Sum(Value1)**

| Date | Level 3 | KPI | Value 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04.12.2023 | E | MIX | 40 |
| 04.12.2023 | F | MIX | 35 |
| 04.12.2023 | G | MIX | 10 |
| 04.12.2023 | H | MIX |  |
| 03.12.2023 | E | MIX | 45 |
| 03.12.2023 | F | MIX |  |
| 03.12.2023 | G | MIX | 5 |
| 03.12.2023 | H | MIX | 15 |

**Result/Expected result at parent 'AB' :**

| DATE | Level2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04.12.2023 | AB (Childs 'E' & 'F') | 75 |
| 03.12.2023 | AB (Childs 'E' & 'F') |  |
| 04.12.2023 | AC (Childs 'G' & 'H') |  |
| 03.12.2023 | AC (Childs 'G' & 'H') | 20 |

Parent ‘AB’ has two childs ‘E’ and ‘F’.
on 03.12.2023  data for F is missing.
How would I stop aggregating for the Parent ‘AB’ when one of its child is missing data?

How would I stop aggregating for the Parent ‘AB’ when one of its child is missing data?

Comment: So in the above example - `04.12.2023 = 75` and `03.12.2023 = BLANK()`? Could you share the full table columns of the above example? Update your question with it as markdown table, add some mock rows and what the desired results would be.

Comment: Update the content above, If one of the child has no value then parent should not show an aggregated data, it should also be Blank

 if this is what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Total1 = 
  IF(
    ISBLANK( COUNTBLANK('YourTable'[Value 1]) ),
    SUM('YourTable'[Value 1])
  )
```